# Sliding window on time in KDB/Q

Tags: aggregate, aggregate-functions, kdb, sliding-window, q-lang

There are some functions in Q/KDB that let us aggregate on a sliding window (msum, mavg, etc.). But these functions takes the number of previous rows into account.

I'd like a function that would aggregate on a sliding window but with time instead of number of rows. For example on the last 5 minutes.

Do such functions exist? If not, how can I design it? I don't want to use a while loop, as it will slow down my program too much because of the huge amount of data.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do you want to aggregate to fixed time buckets `by` and `xbar` are your friend: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/arith-integer/#xbar

```
trade: ([] time:`time$(10:00 10:01 10:03 10:07 10:09); price:`float$(12.1 12.6 12.4 12.4 12.9); size:`int$(5 6 10 34 2))
select last price, sum size by 5 xbar time.minute from trade
minute| price size
------| ----------
10:00 | 12.4  21  
10:05 | 12.9  36
```

if you want to go back 5 minutes in time for every row a window join is what your are looking for: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#wj-wj1-window-join

```
w:-300000 0+\:trade.time
wj1[w;`time;trade;(trade;(last;`price);(sum;`size))]
time         price size
-----------------------
10:00:00.000 12.1  5   
10:01:00.000 12.6  11  
10:03:00.000 12.4  21  
10:07:00.000 12.4  44  
10:09:00.000 12.9  36
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what this line do please:
w:-300000 0+\:trade.time

Comment: Yes. it creates the sliding window for every row. which says current trade time minus 300000 milli seconds to 0/- 0 milli seconds (which is the trade time). Print w to the console and you will get an idea.

Comment: trade.time does not work. I have the following error: nyi. Possibly this error refers to not yet implemented - suggests the operation you are tying to do makes sense but it has not yet been implemented.

Is it the same than trade[`time]?

Comment: That's strange, when I print w:-5000 0+\:tradeWithDV01[`time], I get two timestamps lists that are exactly the same. Shouldn't there be a 5 sec lag between them?

Comment: what's the type of your list? run type tradeWithDV01[`time]

Comment: It's timespan (16h)

Comment: timespan has nano seconds precision. time only millis. sou you need to add a few zeros. w:-300000000000 0+\:tradeWithDV01[`time]

Comment: How would you get 5min moving average at the end of each minute?